# Why is the MCP23S17 device getting too hot suddenly and randomly?

Tags: circuit-design, raspberry-pi, temperature, gpio, mcp23s17

Circuit is a Raspberry Pi 4A SPI master node talking with one [MCP23S17](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20001952C.pdf) device. I'm testing the single-circuit version in a protoboard.

We are using A bank GPIOs for reading, and B bank GPIOs for writing. From them, two GPIOs will be used with wires, one belongs to the input bank and the other one belongs to the output pins group. So Out_1 and In_1 both will have one wire connected at each pin, as can be seen in the picture.

At the end of the wire it could be contact between out_1 wire and in_1 wire or not. So in_1 wire could be reading from out_1 pin or not connected to anything ('Z' state/open circuit).

The input pin is configured with an internal pull-up in order to read VDD when not connected.

Normally out_1 will ever be writing '0', so every time in_1 is connected to out_1 --> in_1 will ever read a '0' value.

The circuit can be seen in the following pictures, when it reads '1':

[image]

When it reads GND:

[image]

This circuit is working at 1 Mhz. As you can see MCP is fed with Raspberry supply pins. They don't need extra capacitors because the Raspberry provides 100 nF at their 3.3 V and 5 V pins.

In the pictures it can be seen that Reset and Address signals have no pull-up, because they will be by the moment to VDD or GND constantly, with any value change. Resistors will be added to the final design where Rst will come from another digital source, instead of VDD.

The application works making thousands of writing/reading in a loop.

It can be working fine during most of the time, for hours.

The problem:

Suddenly the device is reaching too high a temperature, I think it's close to getting burned. Here, reading fails. Even the two contiguous GPIO pins start changing their input values when they are not connected to anything.

When it ocurrs I can see how the multimeter reads 2.8 V instead of 3.3 V from the VDD Raspberry pin. So, it seems to be an extra current consumption, but I don't know from which pin and why.

This situation stops if the device is reset. After making a reset, the temperature falls back to normal and it works fine.

What could be happening? Why is the device getting this power consumption? Does it need resistors at address or reset pins?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmt49a.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Added after posting and some new tests:

I have realized when overcurrent starts. By the moment during a week under test I can say when it happens: when I handle wires and push one of them into the GPIO input pin hole. My Python control software gives me feedback about when an input toggles its input value. I can see on the screen how when overheating has started, a long toggle-switching is produced before becoming stable. The longer the toggle time is, the closer is the start of the undesired behavior.

I have done a hardware debouncing to an input with a 1 μF capacitor and toggle has minimized until being almost completely avoided.

Comment: 1.  Regardless of your opinion, you **do** need decoupling capacitors on the power supply pins of the IC.

Comment: 2. The address and reset pins require external pull ups which you don't provide.

Comment: 3.  A schematic diagram is normally more useful than a wiring diagram.  A wiring diagram or photo of the built circuit can be useful when looking for assmbly errors, but require a schematic to be truly useful.

Comment: @JRE I agree with you on the bypass caps, it might be the reason why it fails. But the address pins are directly grounded, and reset is directly connected to VCC, so the pull-up resistors you mention would not do anything.

Comment: @Justme:  That's the downside of wiring diagrams.  I don't see resistors for the pull ups anywhere, and I didn't go and compare every wired pin to the pinout in the datasheet.  If the pins are tied directly to ground and/or Vcc, then they won't need resistors as pull ups or downs.

Comment: Do you really have the power wires jammed into the same breadboard holes as the IC? Please post a photo of your setup.

Comment: @BruceAbbott:  **Snork.** I hadn't noticed that.  Fritzing is wacky.

Comment: You can monitor the current intake by placing your multimeter in current mode in series with the MCP23S17. Are in_1 and out_1 connected if the heating happens? How did you configurate the "unused" pins? As inputs or as Outputs? Did you enable the pullups for the unused inputs? Background is that non terminated inputs can start floating which can result in undefined behaviour.

Comment: Some background info regarding that topic: https://www.ti.com/lit/an/scba004d/scba004d.pdf?ts=1595064641526&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F

Comment: @JRE thanks for your comments, I did not add Capacitors because because Raspberry provides 100nF at their 3.3V and 5V pins. So I though they don't need extra capacitors. Are they still needing decoupling Cap? I will use capacitors at final design. I won't get 3,3V from Raspberry at future.

Comment: Yes, you **still** need the capacitorson your breadboard despite there being capacitors on the Pi.  You have long wires between the Pi and the breadboard.  Long wires act (a bit) like inductors, so you need local capacitors on the breadboard.

Comment: @Justme this is the reason why I don't use Rpull up yet. I will add them to the final design. About bypass capacitors I'm not completly sure with you both for the same that I've just told to JRE. But I could be wrong, of course.

Comment: Thanks @JRE for your suggestion. I will add a schematic in a few minutes to the original post in order to improve the circuit comprehension. Do you think 100nF Capacitors could be fine? And would you put one capacitor at every IC, then? -I think the answer could be "affirmative". -

Comment: @ChristianB. thanks for share this paper, I think there is a lot of explained things that could be happening here. Regarding your questions: all GPIOs are configured as inputs or outputs. Inputs also have the internal resistor enabled. Paper also talks about pull up for bus signals. I'm also considering to pull up/down SPI signals as paper says.

Comment: you could try and terminate all GPIOs (inputs and outputs) with a 10k to 200k Ohm resistor to ensure that they are always well defined. Are in_1 and out_1 directly connected if the heating happens?

Comment: Christian B. Do you mean tu put a serie resistor between input and output? maybe from pin to Vcc? I'm not sure about whether overheat happened when input and output were connected or it happened when they were not connected. I think it was overheated at two both situations. But I'm doing more tests for cheking that.

Comment: @JRE and company, could be happening something of this? I have just heared about this: http://post.queensu.ca/~saavedra/elec353/Presentations/ELEC-353-Latch-up.pdf

Comment: Regarding my wires distance, there are something like 10cm but they could be longer (up tp 50cm) at final product. I now SPI distance is a critical factor. But we tested this with flat wire and 120Ohms termination and it works even with high freq.

Comment: Updated link: https://web.archive.org/web/20200516083143/post.queensu.ca/~saavedra/elec353/Presentations/ELEC-353-Latch-up.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I don't know yet if this could be the optimal or final solution. But I have realized when overcurrent starts at my circuit.

By the moment during a week under test I can "say" when it happens: when I handle wires driving other logic state value and push one of them into the GPIO input pin hole.

My python control sw:

- configures bank A as inputs with Rpull up, bank B as outputs that writes '0' value every time.
- gives me feedback about when an input toggle its input value by console.

When overheating has started it has been showing how a long toggle-switching is produced before get the stable/final value. As long as toggle time is, too closer to start the undesired situation system is. That makes sense with CMOS literature about switching inputs and overheating.

I have done a hw debouncig to an input with a 1uF capacitor and switching has minimized until almost being completely avoided. But it seems not to trigger the overconsumption. I have not any more overconsumption after debouncing. At least one of the causes here seems to be this.

And so according with this discovering:

It seems to mean that I should be using a number of capacitors = 64 (1 capacitor for every GPIO pin on my board). At this point I don't know whether 64 capacitors is too much or not, it is good or not, etc. I don't use to see examples with one capacitor at every MCU GPIOs that will have more switching value time than my design.

I'm now working on this point.

Comment: You absolutely don't need those capacitors. Just use a resistor, say 100k, to pull each GPIO pin to ground or VCC. **Or** drive those pins as outputs. You must do one of those things: CMOS inputs don't like floating, not even Schmitt trigger inputs.