# Problem in the output current of an PNP current mirror

Tags: power-supply, current, current-mirror

I have a problem in the implementation of a current source, based on an OPAMP voltage-to-current converter followed by a PNP current mirror (see picture).

Indeed, the output currents are identical to the input current in R1 only when the supply of the mirror is 5 V. Unlike in the LTSpice simulation, in the physical circuit their values increase exponentially with the increase of the supply. The input current value is 2 mA. Is there a way to solve this problem? maybe by adding resistors between supply and emitters?

[image: schematic]

Comment: Unlike simulated transistors, discrete transistors are usually not well-matched.  You could add emitter resistors to help if you have the headroom.

Comment: Did you understand my  answer. Reduce your Re and Vin to < 1V or <0.1V

Comment: @JohnD could  1k emitter resistors be sufficient?

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 What do you mean with Re?

Answer (score 2):

The simulation does not show a sufficiently accurate result either:

[image: mirror1]

This is a more accurate version (improved Wilson current mirror):
[image: mirror2]

Comment: When I was doing my rusty EE diploma long long time ago, I only knew that PNP is a "mirror" of NPN, so they form a "complimentary" pair, like N-type and P-type MOS.But I never heard of all PNP "mirroring". OK, I know my EE diploma is so rusty that I should never mention it any longer, to avoid at least my bad friends LOL.

Comment: I wonder why your simulation ramps and mine does not. All collector currents are identical while emitter currents vary with hFE, but none change at all with Vdd ramped to 50V  http://tinyurl.com/y5alyaq7

Comment: @Tony Stewart Sunnyskyguy EE75 Could the 2N2906 [model](https://imgur.com/qZsYATT) be different?

Comment: How? Leakage ? Not at 2mA , hFE sensitivity is low,

Comment: @Tony Stewart Sunnyskyguy EE75 This is my model: .MODEL 2N2906  PNP (
+ IS=15.294E-15
+ BF=297.85
+ VAF=100
+ IKF=1.6607
+ ISE=29.577E-15
+ NE=1.5507
+ BR=476
+ VAR=100
+ IKR=2.2270
+ ISC=7.6418E-9
+ NC=2.1591
+ NK=.97918
+ RB=2.4875
+ RC=.69253
+ CJE=33.186E-12
+ VJE=.8716
+ MJE=.40799
+ CJC=15.649E-12
+ VJC=.56868
+ MJC=.3619
+ TF=456.18E-12
+ XTF=22.393
+ VTF=28.493
+ ITF=.62109
+ TR=10.000E-9 )
******

Comment: @tlfong01 PNP has never been a proper "complementary" pair. The output impedance of the NPN is much higher, the characteristic is straight. PNP is a bad transistor. :) The output impedance is smaller, the characteristic is skewed. This is not very good for the current mirror. :)

Comment: @csabahu, many thanks for pointing out my improper use of the term "mirror" in the context of "current mirror" (a term I only heard this morning! :)). Anyway, I very much agree that PNP BJT is a bad guy, and should not live happily ever after. I think even NPN BJT should disappear, the soon the better. And by the way, I did complete a diploma in EE, but I did not remember I heard of term "leakage"of transistors.

Comment: @csabahu I was wondering if can follow my steps to ascertain why.

Comment: @csabahu Would you suggest to use PMOS instead of PNPs? Also should I substitute the NPN with a Nmos? Thanks

Comment: @alessandro The simplest solution will be to use [dual](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/BCM857BV_BS_DS.pdf) PNP transistors. Accuracy will be [better](https://imgur.com/a/kiINxKe) than 0.5%.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same fault on Falstad’s simulator until I debugged the circuit.

Remember the rules;

1. Investigate
2. Measure everything relevant
3. Compare with component specs
4. Continue until error
5. Analyze
6. Fix
7. Validate if not Repeat

So after walking around each transistor , I discovered for currents < 1mA then hFE sensitivity  is very low. After all there is not enough current to drop any significant Voltage across rE the internal base-emitter bulk resistance, so as long as all transistors have equal Vbe (Thermally tracked) then the current mirror  works from < 1uA to 1mA. Above this then transistor size (rE) and hFE starts to cause differences.  Also remember that Ic=1mA all transistors have Vbe=595mV or 0.60V

### The problem was with your NPN drive greater than Vcc-0.7V when Vcc was near the 5V.

So when making a current sensor, always choose the smallest voltage you can compare such as 50 to 100mV max. Then you shouldn’t have many problems.

But if NPN emitter tries to go higher than the collector from your V2I converter, ya gotta problem.

Proof by [**Simulation**](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgDOB0YzCsICMAmaczLAZgBwuQCyI4CcC6I5YAUAC4jJwBsSKSJyrnEAtIlFmTImyQSTAB2HBJJYpWEDzCQiTEQThYYiAgRxgcCRDDoNmXEIIiI2vfgQnQCWJngkEm49PyUrEawk1tXX1DJBMAd3ZOFBxopCYILGooxhZ-CDSkXXBqACV4pgIkZDii8BBigkyFZAkK5ThqACd4xA54oWKIOBwsdBpWqxK44a6KgZTC4vbOEnSp2YZCTpw4xGoAc0tMZeKx8xoADyQ4Egtia0QEGZYARQ2TrEFWBX6FGxZbkDvkahPCDNsAwmEYwF8Ej8NvQsjZONUrtxFPZHGBnMRPFhZH04O5FMpVOogmAdHoDEZ0KYlrEzOlShU%20JUmJAJMhrpphC5cHAfMpBMJRMhxFIZHI%20uEaFFhuVhvMkFMESByoq5RsoksZbtypKdhBlTAld0qTlEBJ0h1TSxrIoNCy2XAOUwuYZ%20AT-E7EP04M4%20qL6sYaNtFaU4oqtEaosGVsG1vLWoqaVHuhLA7SEplzEtU0sQ-FhjQCqSkGaLiWIBBqkgGlAmgAHNNwtPlV25VLmZsdbXUAD2SAU5U4pVkrug2igsBbG17xW1lX6xX049gJDNzEYVfhlmouEoFQDFYGsBAeQApgBnACWZ9oAEMAHYAYxP29DFQ%20EAAat2ADa3zbPnd12tBAv1-G9-2oIA). 4~50V Current stays constant. hFE sensitivity @ 1uA = 2% thus 50% increase in hFE reduces I by 1%

Comment: OMG, I once earned my living as an electronics troubleshooting technician and the enggr manager did not give me a raise in salary that I wrong thought I deserve. Now I know why I actually did not deserve any higher salary, because instead of 7 rules, I only know one rule: when a (semiconductor testing) machine breaks down, don't ask why, just blindly unplug any circuit board in machine by a good one, if problem does not go away, then try my luck with another circuit board, and another one, until problem disappears, and go for a cup of tea. Ah tea time, would practise use of English tomorrow.